# Unable to click on 'Delete' button in Gmail application in runtime

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

[Click here to see the element i want to click on but i cannot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCWjf.png)

Unable to click on the 'Delete' button in Gmail application
when i inspect the element and write the xpath for it using .....//*[@aria-label='Delete'].... element is being highlighted . but in runtime , it shown as element is not found on the page

Please help. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You need to wait for the delete icon to be loaded once you click on any email from the list.Then try to click it.

Comment: What type of exception you get actually?

Comment: I get this exception : 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate `element: //*[@aria-label='Delete'] `

Answer (score 0):

Try with below locator, to click on Delete button

```
By.cssSelector("div[aria-label='Delete']>div>div")
```

[image]

**Edit-1**

Try with [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class

```
new Actions(driver).click(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[aria-label='Delete']>div>div"))).perform();
```

Comment: Thnks for replying.I still get the same 'NoSuchElementException' even i used the css locator you have suggested

Comment: Try with click method available in Actions class. Updated my answer. Just try with that.

Comment: Still no luck @santosh.  Actually, when I debugged, I came to know that element (delete button) is not visible to the driver object. But it is highlighted on inspecting using xpath/ CSS. I request you to try the scenario practically , so that you will be well known to the issue what i have.

Comment: In which browser are you trying? I've tried the same in firefox40. It is working as expected using Actions class click.

Comment: Am running my script on Firefox Latest version (48.0.2). FYI., am using pageobject model